# Spring Boot: unable to see counter metrics for REST Controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to capture the number of successful calls to a REST Service using the Spring Boot 2 Actuator REST API.
I've included the required dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And enabled all metrics:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

However, I cannot see any counter metrics related to my REST Controller:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
{"names":["application.ready.time","application.started.time","disk.free","disk.total","executor.active","executor.completed","executor.pool.core","executor.pool.max","executor.pool.size","executor.queue.remaining","executor.queued","http.server.requests","jvm.buffer.count","jvm.buffer.memory.used","jvm.buffer.total.capacity","jvm.classes.loaded","jvm.classes.unloaded","jvm.gc.live.data.size","jvm.gc.max.data.size","jvm.gc.memory.allocated","jvm.gc.memory.promoted","jvm.gc.overhead","jvm.memory.committed","jvm.memory.max","jvm.memory.usage.after.gc","jvm.memory.used","jvm.threads.daemon","jvm.threads.live","jvm.threads.peak","jvm.threads.states","logback.events","process.cpu.usage","process.files.max","process.files.open","process.start.time","process.uptime","system.cpu.count","system.cpu.usage","system.load.average.1m","tomcat.sessions.active.current","tomcat.sessions.active.max","tomcat.sessions.alive.max","tomcat.sessions.created","tomcat.sessions.expired","tomcat.sessions.rejected"]}
```

Do I have to add any extra annotation to the REST Controller endpoint or in a Configuration Bean?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should already be there.

`curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll save save your suggestion!